# geometric meaning of conjugate points

Tags: differential-geometry

Recently I am reading Manfredo do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*. He said the $q$ is the conjugate point of $p$ with respect to a geodesic $\gamma$ joining the two points if there exists a Jacobi field which vanishes on the $p$ and $q$. (Here he assumes all the surfaces are complete).
He gives this as a geometric meaning without explanation:

Fix a point $p$ on the surface $S$. Then 1. Any geodesic passing from $p$ would be tangent to the conjugate locus. 2. if $\gamma$ is a geodesic emmiting from $p$ and $\bar\gamma$ is another geodesic emmiting from $p$ with different direction. Then the intersection point of $\gamma$ and $\bar\gamma$ would approach closer and closer to the conjugate point as $\gamma$ and $\bar\gamma$ approach closer to each other. That is, the conjugate point is the point of intersection of two 'infinitely close' geodesics.

How to prove the above two assertion?